# Notifications system with MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, notifications

My android app talks to the **MySQL** backend using a **PHP** API. The app allows readers to follow different authors, and get notifications when one of the authors they are following, submits an article.

Right now I am doing this by storing a new record for each each of the author's followers. i.e : If an author with 1000 followers submits an article, it adds in 1000 new rows, with the `seen` column set to `FALSE`.

Now when the mobile app requests unseen notifications, I can show just those records, setting `seen` to `TRUE`.

However, this scales with some difficulty. An bunch of authors with 300k+ followers, for example, will create a large number of rows.

Is this simply the cost of such a system? Or is there a more efficient way to handle this, perhaps from the app's side?

```
Table : posts (Only the relevant columns)
-------------
id : INT(10) PK,NN,AI
author_id : INT(10) NN,UN


Table : followers
-----------------
id : INT(10) PK,NN,AI
author_id : INT(10) NN,UN
user_id : INT(10) NN,UN

Table : notifications
---------------------
id    :  INT(10) PK,NN,AI
user_id : INT(10) NN,UN
author_id : INT(10) NN,UN
seen : VARCHAR(1) NN
```

A few Table Notes:

1. Every time a user follows an author, a new row is created in the `followers` table with the `user_id` of the reader, and the `author_id` of the person being subscribed to. Total rows at any point will be equal to the sum of the follower counts of all users.
2. When an author submits a post, one new row gets created for each of their followers, in the `notifications` table, with the `seen` column set to `FALSE`. The app then sends another call, to mark them seen. Does the job, but a huge amount of data gets added in constantly.
3. When the app requests notifications, all the unseen rows from the `notifications` table that pertain to the current user, are retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of ways you can do this better.  Here's one simple way-  you can use a timestamp.  Keep track of the last time a user requested notifications.  Then when they next request notifications, query for all the articles with a timestamp later than that time.  Those are his notifications.  Requires either 1 row per user, or 1 column per user depending on if you make a new table or just a new column for last check time.

Comment: This is the first thing that I tried, but I am trying to avoid declaring that all posts made before my last check, are read. It creates a problem that is worth resolving with the added overhead of the above solution. Is there any way to overcome that?

Comment: Sure, but they're a lot more work-  they're basically hybrids of the two.  Your tradeoff here is accuracy, amount of data, and complexity of code.  You could also go back to your original solution but basically reverse the situation-  add in a row only when the user visits the article.  So no row=new, row present=seen.  This would require many fewer rows, but they'll be added as needed.  You can also consider saving data by expiring notification-  only notify on articles in the past week, so all rows older than 1 week can be deleted.

Comment: If you decide to go a hybrid route to cut down data used at the expense of complexity-  take a look at how TCP keeps track of what packets have been seen and what are pending using a sliding window.  If you ignore the retransmit part, its basically the same problem.

Comment: Reversing the situation looks interesting. But is there no way to not sacrifice the accuracy there? (Getting by timestamp would still kill the unread notifications from the previous pull)